# What do we mean by "bias" in particle physics

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics

Suppose I have some distribution of unweighted and weighted data. So, what is meant when the weighted data is having "10% maximum bias"? Does it mean that the weighted data matches the original correct distribution (like for example, MC Truth) 10% better than what unweighted data do?

Comment: can you give a link to an analysis where this terminology is used?

Comment: @annav Sorry, I had heard this statement in some meeting where they were discussing some distribution for two differently weighted dataset and the MC Truth dataset. (Could be that I may have heard this statement incorrectly, but to what I remember, someone commented during the meeting that "one of the weighted dataset had 10% maximum bias"). All I know about biasing is in general like applying a trigger introduces bias and so on, ... So I was thinking about what he probably meant by his statement...